# WMI query or Powershell command that retrieves a sampling of historic CPU and memory usage for Hyper-V

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, wmi

I need to programmatically retrieve a sampling of recent CPU & memory usage on a Hyper-V system, as seen by the guest OS. By recent, I mean within the last few mins.

I can't customize the target Hyper-V system (neither the host nor the guest). And so I can't configure performance logs or install custom features.

I was hoping to do this via a WMI query, but was unable to identify a WMI class that gives historical CPU or memory.

I tried the get-counter ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.3)) cmd, but it doesn't pull historical data. Rather, it appears to start sampling at the time I run the cmd. And so doesn't fit my needs.

The Get-ClusterPerformanceHistory cmd ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/performance-history-for-vms#usage-in-powershell)) looked promising, but it requires the Windows Storage spaces feature, which is a no-go in my case.

Is there a way, via a WMI query or a powershell cmd, to do what I need?

Comment: Windows doesn't have a native capability for that. There's a reason that performance solutions exist.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are out of luck. You cannot get what is not recorded. You need to use the API for the performance monitor - but it only records when it has instructions to do it and unless someone has configured that - without you being able to do that (as it is a change in the system) - tell whoever gave you that task to talk to Santa.

> The Get-ClusterPerformanceHistory cmd (ref) looked promising, but it
> requires the Windows Storage spaces feature

Why would you even say that given that this is a feature that to 90% relies on cluster being there with storage spaces and mostly records data for that.